# IllegalArgumentException - H2O Importing MOJO File Failed in Python

Tags: python, h2o, illegalargumentexception, mojo

MOJO model generation done in H2O(3.28.0.2). File named ep_gbm_grid03_model_49.zip exported.

When a MOJO import job (http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/save-and-load-model.html#mojo-models) issued in H2O (3.28.0.2) Python terminal like below,

```
import h2o
h2o.init()
path = "/Users/maya/Downloads/ep_gbm_grid03_model_49.zip"
imported_model = h2o.import_mojo(path)
```

the following exception dumped...

```
EnvironmentError: Job with key $03017f00000132d4ffffffff$_8faceff652ec107419c1688af40247ee failed with an exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: colTypes values must be one of "double", "float", "int", "long", or "string"
stacktrace: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: colTypes values must be one of "double", "float", "int", "long", or "string"
    at water.util.TwoDimTable.<init>(TwoDimTable.java:85)
    at hex.generic.GenericModelOutput.convertTable(GenericModelOutput.java:250)
    at hex.generic.GenericModelOutput.<init>(GenericModelOutput.java:35)
    at hex.generic.Generic$MojoDelegatingModelDriver.computeImpl(Generic.java:95)
    at hex.ModelBuilder$Driver.compute2(ModelBuilder.java:239)
    at hex.generic.Generic$MojoDelegatingModelDriver.compute2(Generic.java:71)
    at water.H2O$H2OCountedCompleter.compute(H2O.java:1455)
    at jsr166y.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:468)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:263)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:974)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1477)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)
```

Comment: can you send the logs to support@h2o.ai and refer to this post?

Comment: Hello XentneX, it would be helpful to have your MOJO sent to `support@h2o.ai`. Or any MOJO that reproduces this issue. Thank you.